# Using colors in feature detection

Tags: computer-vision

Is there any feature detector or extractor that uses color information?

Detectors like SURF and SIFT and many others work with grayscale. How do you think, may be transform can be sued to generate a grayscale image without loosing color info but suitable for those algorithms?

In particular, I need to distinguish objects similar in shape, but of different color. And in general, color provide more information about objects, and allows to classify them with better performance, that's why we have color vision.

Comment: If you convert your color image to grayscale, you will probably still be able to apply your detector, in the same way that black and white movies are legible. To maximize the success probability, inject some randomness into the conversion (add some randomness to the coefficients).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, most of the detectors use grayscale.